# Can not install Netbeans after upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, netbeans

This is the message error from the terminal :

```
coca@Bakorng:/var/www/shared$ sh netbeans-7.2-ml-php-linux.sh 
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
Can`t initialize UI
Running in headless mode

Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in     thread "main"
coca@Bakorng:/var/www/shared$
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your report is similar to [this one](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210664) which suggests simply uninstalling OpenJDK 6 and using the latest version of OpenJDK 7 instead.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the sh installer does not work with the openJDK 7. 
Quick fix to install is to change back to JDK 6. 
run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
(select java 6) 
sh netbeans-7.2.1-ml-linux.sh
```

the installer should run and then just switch back to the java 7 JDK with update-alternatives.